# Python find "xxh" from string and replace into xx:00 AM/PM in existing string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, time

> Look this Example: [Google Agenda](https://www.google.com/calendar)
>
> go to *Month*  >>  select any *date* >> Open popup box Enter "*15h going to swimming with friends*"
>   [image]

[image]

Now my question is how to I find **`"XXh"`** substring from whole string message ?

that substring are replace to following way,

```
8:00 => 8:00 AM
19:00 => 7:00 PM
19h  => 7:00 PM
8am => 8:00 AM
at OAT => Location OAT
7 to 7:30 => 7:00 AM to 7:30 AM
```

I try to made pattern,

```
(\d{1,2}h)|(\d{1,2}:\d{2})|(\d{1,2}(am|pm))\gi
```

#### Python

```
>>> message = raw_input("Enter Agenda Message: ")
Enter Agenda Message: 15h going to swimming with friends
>>> message
'15h going to swimming with friends'
```

How to I make **RegEXP** to find **"15h"** from the string and replace to new **3pm**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Pattern <kbd>[Live](https://regex101.com/r/fV1mU6/1)</kbd>

```
(\d{1,2}h)|(\d{1,2}:\d{2})|(\d{1,2}(?:am|pm))|((?!\s)at(?=\s))
```

#### Python

```
import re
def time_replace(timeword):
    timestr = timeword.group().lower()
    flag = None
    if 'h' in timestr:
        flag = 1
    elif ':' in timestr:
        flag = 2
    elif 'm' in timestr:
        flag = 3
    elif 'at' in timestr: 
        return "Location"

    if flag == 1:
        hour = timestr.split('h')[0]
        if int(hour) > 12 and int(hour) < 24:
            return str(int(hour) - 12) + ":00 PM"
        elif int(hour) == 24:
            return str(int(hour) - 12) + ":00 AM"
        elif int(hour) == 12:
            return hour + ":00 PM"
        else:
            return hour + ":00 AM"
    elif flag == 2:
        hour, minute = timestr.split(':')
        if int(hour) > 12 and int(hour) < 24:
            return str(int(hour) - 12) + ":" + minute + " PM"
        elif int(hour) == 24:
            return str(int(hour) - 12) + ":" + minute + " AM"
        elif int(hour) == 12:
            return hour + ":" + minute + " PM"
        else:   
            return hour + ":" + minute + " AM"
    elif flag == 3:
        time = re.search(r"\d+(\.\d+)?", timestr).group()
        hour, ampm = time[-2:], timestr[-2:]
        meridiem = " PM" if 'pm' in ampm else " AM"
        return "%s:00%s" % (hour, meridiem)
    else:
        return timestr

agenda = """
    ---------------------------------------
    8h going swimming with friends
    16H going swimming with friends

    8:00 going swimming with friends
    08:35 going swimming with friends

    8pm going for dinner
    8AM going swimming with friends     
    7PM going for dinner at ahmedabad
    9am going swimming with friends"""

print agenda
print re.sub(r"(\d{1,2}h)|(\d{1,2}:\d{2})|(\d{1,2}(?:am|pm))|((?!\s)at(?=\s))", time_replace, agenda, flags=re.I|re.M)
```

#### Interpret <kbd>[Live](http://ideone.com/nVcTmP)</kbd>

```
8:00 AM going swimming with friends
4:00 PM going swimming with friends

8:00 AM going swimming with friends
08:35 AM going swimming with friends

8:00 PM going for dinner
8:00 AM going swimming with friends     
7:00 PM going for dinner Location ahmedabad
9:00 AM going swimming with friends
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can find the `15h` with `re.search` and then convert 15 to 3 with `15%12` and then replace with `re.sub` :

```
>>> def convert(s):
...     t=re.search(r'\b(\d+)\S\b',s).group(1)
...     if int(t) < 12 :
...          new=str(int(t))+'am'
...     elif int(t)==24 :
...          new='12am'
...     else :
...          new=str(abs(int(t)-12))+'pm'
...     return re.sub(r'\b\d+\S\b',new,s)
... 
>>> s="24h going to swimming with friends"
>>> convert(s)
'12am going to swimming with friends'
>>> s="08h going to swimming with friends"
>>> convert(s)
'8am going to swimming with friends'
>>> s="17h going to swimming with friends"
>>> convert(s)
'5pm going to swimming with friends'
```

Comment: I update demo example case in question, can you please recheck. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def repl(matchobj):
    if int(matchobj.group().split('h')[0])>12 and int(matchobj.group().split('h')[0])<24:
        return str(int(matchobj.group().split('h')[0])-12)+"pm"
    elif int(matchobj.group().split('h')[0])==24:
        return str(int(matchobj.group().split('h')[0])-12)+"am"
    elif int(matchobj.group().split('h')[0])==12:
        return str(int(matchobj.group().split('h')[0]))+"pm"
    else:
        return str(int(matchobj.group().split('h')[0]))+"am"

x="08h going to swimming with friends"
print re.sub(r"\d{1,2}h",repl,x)
```

Try this.This works for all cases.

Comment: I update demo example case in question, can you please recheck. thanks

Comment: I made this pattern https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/1 but still confuse how to archive this.

Comment: could you please help how to find AM/PM case. can you view regexp pattern link https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/1

Comment: @user1153551 will look into in once i reach home.Till then try with this https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/2 if you have `am|pm` after split simply return with `:00` appended

Comment: but please look this. Thank you so much

Comment: hello i m done almost. do not put your effort on this question. and thank you so much.

Comment: @user1153551 how did you do it